# Finding the correct import for a third party DefinitelyTyped module

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I'm trying to add [Vanilla Tilt](https://micku7zu.github.io/vanilla-tilt.js/) to my TypeScript project. I've installed it and the [`@types/vanilla-tilt`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/vanilla-tilt/index.d.ts)

The types have:

```
export namespace VanillaTilt {
...
}

export default class VanillaTilt {
  static init(...)
}
```

In my code, I'm doing variations of `import ... from 'vanilla-tilt';`. I'm trying to use `VanillaTilt.init`.

I haven't been able to find a way to do this without doing something like `(VanillaTilt as any).init`.

```
// misnamed import. Import should be named `vanillaTilt` but found `VanillaTilt`
import VanillaTilt from 'vanilla-tilt';

// Property 'init' does not exist on typeof node_modules/@types/vanilla-tilt/index
import vanillaTilt from 'vanilla-tilt';
import { default as VanillaTilt } from 'vanilla-tilt';

// TypeScript does not throw an error, but I get `cannot read property init of undefined`.
import { VanillaTilt } from 'vanilla-tilt';
```

Is there something wrong with the type definition that can be correct to import this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type definitions are broken. The definitions use a named export:

```
export class VanillaTilt {
```

But the actual source code uses a default export:

```
export default class VanillaTilt {
```

I'd suggest making a pull request to DefinitelyTyped to fix it. In the PR, use `export = class VanillaTilt` (as suggested in the comments) to align with the usage in CommonJS. Roll your own fixed definitions until it's merged. You should be able to use it like so:

```
import VanillaTilt from 'vanilla-tilt'
VanillaTilt.init(...)
```

I'll add that the "misnamed import" error you get on this form is actually a linter error, not a compiler error. You should be able to disable that rule in your linter configuration, or add a comment to exempt it.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Great that you differentiated between the linter error and the TypeScript error! Just one small correction. Based on the source, vanilla-tilt is actually a CommonJS module. So the declarations should use `export = ` not `export default`. The correct way to import it _is_ still as if it were the `default` though. https://github.com/micku7zu/vanilla-tilt.js/blob/master/lib/vanilla-tilt.js#L319

Comment: Thanks for the comment and correction. I was actually looking at this line here, but `export =` would still probably be more correct. https://github.com/micku7zu/vanilla-tilt.js/blob/b3c1dbadfeaee6b7fda919ca436791c63311fde2/lib/vanilla-tilt.es2015.js#L310

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the ecosystem is kind of broken right now. The source indeed exports only a `default`. This gets compiled into an assignment to `module.exports` which then gets in turn gets mapped back to a `default` export by the ESM <-> CJS interop process. It is really hard to know what form to pick without reading the compiled source.

Comment: @kingdaro I will make a PR for it; should I use `export =` as suggested in your answer? If so, will you update it? Otherwise I’ll do what’s in your answer.

Comment: @kingdaro in this particular case I get `cannot use namespace VanillaTilt as a type` and `an export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements`. I don't get an error with `export default class` though but idk if  that will work properly based on what you've said.

Comment: Hm, definitions and exports are finicky in TS. I fiddled around with it a bit and this seems to work: https://gist.github.com/kingdaro/10bfd37cadb68e10c4fbd68cb09452cd

Comment: im new to TS... anybody have a set of instruction on how to accomplish this fix?

Comment: @kingdaro I have the same issue. Im not able to find clear steps to fix this... What file should I modify?

Comment: @Omar The original solution was to make a PR to actually fix the definitions, but it doesn't look like a PR was ever created or merged ? Either way, if you put [this](https://gist.github.com/kingdaro/26a84d7053f6fa3102ef0ba0c8250edd) in a .d.ts file it should work (doesn't matter where, as long as it's included in your tsconfig like any other ts file)

Comment: @kingdaro I am so happy to have ur attention... I have been trying lots of what you just shared but TS errors out `export assignments are not permitted`

Comment: Does it work if you change `export =` at the bottom to `export default`?

Comment: If not, make a new question instead of continuing it here

Comment: `'"vanilla-tilt"' has no default export` that is with `export =` and `export default`

Comment: @kingdaro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49329739/importing-definitelytyped-module-angular