# importing DefinitelyTyped module angular

Tags: angular, typescript, definitelytyped

I have the same problem as this post => [Finding the correct import for a third party DefinitelyTyped module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48737973/finding-the-correct-import-for-a-third-party-definitelytyped-module/48740069?noredirect=1#comment85660658_48740069)

I am trying to install [VanillaTilt](https://github.com/micku7zu/vanilla-tilt.js) in to my Angular (TS) project. Using this [index.d.ts](https://gist.github.com/kingdaro/26a84d7053f6fa3102ef0ba0c8250edd)... I saved that `d.ts` in the same directory as `app.component.ts` which looks like the following

```
    import VanillaTilt from 'vanilla-tilt';
    VanillaTilt.init(document.createElement('a'), { perspective: 1000  });
```

but i get the following ts error
`ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(3,8): error TS1192: Module '"vanilla-tilt"' has no default export.`

I also tried [this version](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/vanilla-tilt) of the `d.ts` but i kept getting `Cannot read property 'init' of undefined`

Does anyone have any advice on how to use [VanillaTilt](https://github.com/micku7zu/vanilla-tilt.js) in agular5?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536186/using-vanilla-js-code-in-angular-2-angular-cli#42536482

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typings are available on npm now. First install them

```
npm install --save-dev @types/vanilla-tilt
```

Then remove your local .d.ts files

Next, the correct syntax for importing is

```
import { VanillaTilt } from 'vanilla-tilt';
```

Because VanillaTilt has a named export , not a default export.